# Adding multiple schemas to schemainclusionrule schema crawler

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, schemacrawler

I have to add selected schemas to be crawled using schemacrawler. How can we add multiple schemas into inclusion rule of schemacrawler?

like :

```
final SchemaCrawlerOptions options = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
options.setSchemaInclusionRule(new InclusionRule("schema1,schema2", InclusionRule.NONE));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InclusionRule](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/apidocs/schemacrawler/schemacrawler/InclusionRule.html) accepts regexp pattern. You can pass java.util.regex.Pattern instance or String, in latter case it will be compiled for you. If I am not mistaken, you can use `|` sign to make pattern match multiple options. E.g., `"schema1|schema2"`.

You can test your patterns with a simple program; e.g.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("schema1|schema2");
        System.out.println(p.matcher("schema0").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("schema1").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("schema2").matches());
        System.out.println(p.matcher("schema3").matches());
    }
}
```

.. which prints:

```
false
true
true
false
```

Comment: ya now i am able to get traverse selected schemas, Thanks a lot !